# Is there a word for "one who has never sinned"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for "one who has never sinned"?
I can think of "innocent" of course, which means "free from sin or blame" except that it doesn't include the emphasis on not having sinned ever in the past.

Comment: The word is "sinless".

Comment: @RonMaimon The opposite of `sinful` is `ןnɟuᴉs`  — or perhaps `sinempty`. 

Comment: @tchrist: what's wrong with sinless? "Judge, you say I have done wrong, but I am sinless as Christ and the virgin mother!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That word is *immaculate*, as in *immaculate conception*.  [Per the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/91787), it means

> Free from spot or stain; pure, spotless, unblemished, undefiled. In *fig*. senses.

Comment: Could impeccable work as well? They both appear as synonyms to the simple word "sinless". What is the difference? 
Can I say: "the sincerely repented enjoy the purity of the immaculate [i.e. one who has never sinned]"?

Comment: Per [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impeccable) yes impeccable *can* mean 'not capable of sinning or liable to sin' but it's more commonly used with the second meaning - flawless, without religious connotations.

Comment: @tchrist  I thought there is a Christian name for such a person, isnt there? That, having come from Greek or Latin could have been used, right?

Comment: @Shivadas The orginal Latin sense of *impeccable* is no longer the most common one. Then again, the same can be said of *immaculate*. In modern parlance, these words are used without their religious senses, because the whole sin thing as “a transgression against God’s will” is not exactly prevalent in today’s Zeitgeist, so it will be given a secular interpretation.

Comment: @tchrist +1, agreed.

Comment: @karthik "Immaculate" is a girl's name according to [The Bump](https://www.thebump.com/b/immaculate-baby-name) baby name website. They say it comes from Spanish but other sites show it as Irish and the Spanish name as Immaculata. You does your cost-free seach and you takes your choice I guess!